# Convert mongo query into spring query

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

MY mongo cli query

```
  {$project:{"userId":{$setIntersection:["array1","array2"]}}}
```

I want to convert it into spring aggregation projection.

I write following query

```
  var intersection=SetOperators.arrayAsSet("array1").intersects("pipe1","pipe2")

  var afterFacetStage=Aggregation.project().and(intersection).`as`("userId")
```

this is equivalent to

```
{$project:{"userId":{$setIntersection:["array1","pipe1","pipe2"]}}}
```

Its not expected I dont want to include arrayAsSet

[Spring SetOperator Api](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.1.3.RELEASE/api/)

I found one another way after seeing SetOperator class code

```
  var intersectOperation=SetOperators.SetOperatorFactory("array1").intersects("pipe1","pipe2")
    var afterFacetStage1=Aggregation.project().and(intersectOperation).`as`("userId")
```

still its generate this query which is not expected

```
 {$project:{"userId":{$setIntersection:["array1","pipe1","pipe2"]}}}
```

Comment: What is pipe1 and pipe2 and how it is related to array2 from cli query ?

Comment: these are array which contain id field and i want only those id which are common in both array pipe1,pipe2.here array1,pipe1,pip2 are array .                          I want to convert above mongo cli query into spring aggregation query.

Comment: sorry for inconvenient naming array1,array2,pipe1,pipe2 all are arrays.I am using facet where pipeline generated dynamically after facet operation i want list of those document(id) which are common in all facet pipeline.                                  My real query is shown below-

Comment: aggregate([
{$facet:{
"pipe1":[
{$match:{"name":"Search","creationTime":{$gt:new ISODate("2018-08-01T12:00:00Z")},"attributes.Item":"laptop","attributes.Color":"black"}},
{$group:{_id:"$userId",count:{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{count:{$gt:0}}}
],
"pipe2":[
{$match:{"name":"Search Category","creationTime":{$gt:new ISODate("2018-08-01T12:00:00Z"),$lt:new ISODate("2018-08-28T12:00:00Z")},"attributes.Category":{$in:["men"]}}},
{$group:{_id:"$userId",count:{$sum:1}}},
{$match:{count:{$gt:1}}}
]
}}
,
{$project:{"userId":{"$setIntersection":["$pipe1._id","$pipe2._id"]}}}
}